# Powershell change AD variable "PasswordLastSet"

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, powershell

Is it possible to edit the PasswordLastSet value via powershell (or any method?)?

If that is not possible, is there anyway i can set so a users password (not account) expires in X amount of days.

I can clearly see the value with Get-ADUser, but i can't seem to edit it using Set-ADuser.

Comment: You could set a scheduled task to run `Set-ADUser -Identity <samAccountName> -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true` on a given date/time

Comment: Sadly that doesn't solve my issue. I want to change the value when the password was set or make the password have a lower expiry date than the domain rule

Comment: The above has the same result, it will force the user to change their password on next logon. It wouldn't matter if it had "expired" or not. I don't think you can change that value

Comment: No, it does not have the same result. I want to be able to set "PasswordLastSet" to "get-date -30 days".

Comment: Is the end result - to get the user to change the password at a given time rather then when it is due to expire?

Comment: I want to trigger a specific action that only happens when users have X amount of days left to expire the password. This would only apply to a few users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change that value, its protected. The only value you can manually put is 0 or -1. 0 will force a user password change (as like expired), -1 behave like the password will not expire.

Comment: Issue is I dont want to expire the password, i only want to put it close to being expired. 

My current idea would be creating a new GPO and change how long the password lasts and block the domain default. But would prefer to not have to do that.

Comment: @Jakodns You really cant change that field :( you will have to use fine grained password policy https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2012/05/29/creating-fine-grained-password-policies-through-gui-windows-server-2012-server-8-beta/

Comment: I guess this is as "solved" as it gets then.

Answer (score 0):

in case you change your mind here is the solution to bulk modify last [passwordsetdate](http://allenage.com/question/bulk-modify-ad-users-last-password-set-date/)

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
$Ou=’Cn=users, Dc=domain, Dc=com’ # select OU where users resides  Set-QADUser -SearchRoot $Ou | Set-QADUser -ObjectAttributes @{pwdLastSet=0}
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $OU | Set-QADUser -ObjectAttributes @{pwdLastSet=’-1′}
```